# SQLAlchemy 2 generic mixin

Tags: python, generics, sqlalchemy

My goal is to create a generic mixin, which concept can best be explained by an example:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

T = TypeVar("T")

class MyGenericMixin(Generic[T]):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    my_data: Mapped[T] = mapped_column(nullable=False)

class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class MyIntImpl(Base, MyGenericMixin[int]):
    __tablename__ = "my_int_impl"

class MyStrImpl(Base, MyGenericMixin[str]):
    __tablename__ = "my_str_impl"

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///example.db")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Is something similar possible in SQLAlchemy 2?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using `__init__subclass__` to retrieve the actual type of T, store it, and use it when the actual column is defined. It looks like magic but it actually makes sense and proves to be quite reliable.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, get_args, get_origin, ClassVar, Type
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    Mapped,
    mapped_column,
    MappedAsDataclass,
    DeclarativeBase,
    declared_attr,
    mapped_column,
)
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, String

T = TypeVar("T")


class MyGenericMixin(MappedAsDataclass, Generic[T]):
    __type_t: ClassVar[Type[T]]  # stores the type of T.

    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, **kwargs) -> None:
        """set __type_t to the type of T."""
        # find MyGenericMixin and its type annotations in the list of base classes
        orig_base_indices = [
            i
            for i, v in enumerate(cls.__orig_bases__)
            if get_origin(v) is MyGenericMixin
        ]
        assert len(orig_base_indices) == 1
        orig_base = cls.__orig_bases__[orig_base_indices[0]]
        # get the type of T from the type annotations
        generic_types = get_args(orig_base)
        assert len(generic_types) == 1
        cls.__type_t = generic_types[0]

        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False, init=False,
    )

    @declared_attr
    def my_data(cls):
        """
        define the column.

        have to use a property because the type is variable and retrieved in __init_subclass__.
        """
        type_mapping = {
            int: Integer,
            str: String,
        }
        assert cls.__type_t in type_mapping, "Type not supported."
        return mapped_column(type_mapping[cls.__type_t], nullable=False)


class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class MyIntImpl(Base, MyGenericMixin[int]):
    __tablename__ = "my_int_impl"


class MyStrImpl(Base, MyGenericMixin[str]):
    __tablename__ = "my_str_impl"


engine = create_engine("sqlite:///example.db")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as ses:
    ses.add(MyIntImpl(3))
    ses.add(MyStrImpl("test"))
    ses.commit()
```

It becomes more complicated if it must pass `mypy`. If anyone figures out how remove the `type: ignore`s, let me know. Furthermore, as far as I know an `if TYPE_CHECKING` needs to be used to have mypy properly understand `my_data` is an argument for `__init__` (so a dataclass member variable).

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, get_args, get_origin, ClassVar, Type, List, TYPE_CHECKING, Dict, Any
from typing_extensions import Self
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    Mapped,
    mapped_column,
    MappedAsDataclass,
    DeclarativeBase,
    declared_attr,
    mapped_column,
)
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, String, ForeignKey

T = TypeVar("T")


class MyGenericMixin(MappedAsDataclass, Generic[T]):
    __type_t: ClassVar[Type[T]]  # type: ignore[misc]

    def __init_subclass__(cls: Type[Self], /, **kwargs: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
        """Set __type_t to the type of T."""
        # find MyGenericMixin and its type annotations in the list of base classes
        orig_bases: List[Type[Self]] = [orig_base for orig_base in cls.__orig_bases__ if get_origin(orig_base) is MyGenericMixin]  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
        assert len(orig_bases) == 1
        orig_base = orig_bases[0]
        # get the type of T from the type annotations
        generic_types = get_args(orig_base)
        assert len(generic_types) == 1
        cls.__type_t = generic_types[0]

        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs) #type: ignore[arg-type]

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False, init=False
    )

    def __my_data_impl(cls) -> Mapped[T]:
        """
        define the column.

        have to use a property because the type is variable and retrieved in __init_subclass__.
        """
        type_mapping = {
            int: Integer,
            str: String,
        }
        assert cls.__type_t in type_mapping, "Type not supported."
        return mapped_column(type_mapping[cls.__type_t], nullable=False)

    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        my_data: Mapped[T] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    else:
        @declared_attr
        def my_data(cls) -> Mapped[T]:
            return cls.__my_data_impl(cls)


class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class MyIntImpl(Base, MyGenericMixin[int]):
    __tablename__ = "my_int_impl"


class MyStrImpl(Base, MyGenericMixin[str]):
    __tablename__ = "my_str_impl"


engine = create_engine("sqlite:///example.db")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as ses:
    ses.add(MyIntImpl(3))
    ses.add(MyStrImpl("test"))
    ses.commit()
```